# YAML syntax to reference an array

Tags: yaml

I've got a YAML file where I want to reuse a set of values in several sections. Here's a simplified form:

```
.mylist:
  things:
    - thing1
    - thing2

realthings:
  things:
    - !reference [.mylist, things]
    - thing3
```

The intention here is that `realthings` should have 3 items in the `things` list. But I think what's happening here is that it has 2 `things`, the first being a list of `[thing1, thing2]`, and the second is `thing3`.

What's the correct syntax to achieve the intended outcome?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [here](https://blog.daemonl.com/2016/02/yaml.html): use anchors.

```
.mylist: &mythings
    - thing1
    - thing2

realthings:
  things: *mythings
    - thing3
```